# QResizeEvent causes SIGSEGV

Tags: c++, qt, resize, qwidget, segmentation-fault

My purpose is to use a class called `overlay.h` to add a rectangular box and text on top of a `Widget` (MarbleWidget). Here below is my code for the GUI. I tried to remove all unnecessary parts:

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent)
{
    setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
}

void MainWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
    overlay->resize(event->size());   //////////////// CAUSES SIGSEGV!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    event->accept();
}

void MainWindow::setupUi(QMainWindow *MainWindow)
{
    MainWindow->showMaximized();
    QSizePolicy sizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
    sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0);
    sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0);
    sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(MainWindow->sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth());
    MainWindow->setSizePolicy(sizePolicy);
    MainWindow->setTabShape(QTabWidget::Rounded);

    QWidget *centralwidget = new QWidget(MainWindow);
    centralwidget->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("centralwidget"));
    sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(centralwidget->sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth());
    centralwidget->setSizePolicy(sizePolicy);
    centralwidget->setLayoutDirection(Qt::LeftToRight);

    QGridLayout *gridLayout_4 = new QGridLayout(centralwidget);
    gridLayout_4->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("gridLayout_4"));

    QSplitter *splitter_4 = new QSplitter(centralwidget);
    splitter_4->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("splitter_4"));
    splitter_4->setOrientation(Qt::Horizontal);

    QTabWidget *tabWidget_2 = new QTabWidget(splitter_4);
    tabWidget_2->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("tabWidget_2"));
    sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(tabWidget_2->sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth());
    tabWidget_2->setSizePolicy(sizePolicy);
    tabWidget_2->setMaximumSize(QSize(443, 16777));
    tabWidget_2->setAutoFillBackground(true);
    tabWidget_2->setTabPosition(QTabWidget::West);
    tabWidget_2->setTabShape(QTabWidget::Rounded);
    tabWidget_2->setIconSize(QSize(30, 16));

    QWidget *tab_10 = new QWidget();
    tab_10->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("tab_10"));
    QGridLayout *gridLayout = new QGridLayout(tab_10);
    gridLayout->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("gridLayout"));
    QVBoxLayout  *verticalLayout_4 = new QVBoxLayout();
    verticalLayout_4->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("verticalLayout_4"));
    QHBoxLayout *horizontalLayout_7 = new QHBoxLayout();
    horizontalLayout_7->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("horizontalLayout_7"));
    QLabel *label_3 = new QLabel(tab_10);
    label_3->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("label_3"));
    horizontalLayout_7->addWidget(label_3);

    verticalLayout_4->addLayout(horizontalLayout_7);
    QTreeView *treeView_4 = new QTreeView(tab_10);
    treeView_4->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("treeView_4"));
    QStandardItemModel *standardModel = new QStandardItemModel ;
    QStandardItem *rootNode = standardModel->invisibleRootItem();
    treeView_4->setModel(standardModel);
    verticalLayout_4->addWidget(treeView_4);
    gridLayout->addLayout(verticalLayout_4, 0, 0, 1, 1);

    tabWidget_2->addTab(tab_10, QString());
    treeView_4->raise();

    Marble::MarbleWidget* MarbleWidget = new Marble::MarbleWidget(splitter_4);

    splitter_4->addWidget(MarbleWidget);
    splitter_4->setStretchFactor(0,0);
    splitter_4->setStretchFactor(1,6);
    gridLayout_4->addWidget(splitter_4, 0, 0, 1, 1);

    MainWindow->setCentralWidget(centralwidget);
    MarbleWidget->raise();
    tabWidget_2->raise();

    overlay = new Overlay(MarbleWidget);
    overlay->raise();

    QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(MainWindow);
} // setupUi
```

**overlay.h**

```
    #include <QWidget>
    #include <QPainter>

    class Overlay : public QWidget
    {
    public:
        Overlay(QWidget *parent);

    protected:
        void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);
    };
```

**overlay.cpp**

```
#include "overlay.h"

Overlay::Overlay(QWidget *parent)
: QWidget(parent)
{
    setPalette(Qt::transparent);
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents);
}

void Overlay::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QFont font;
    font.setStyleHint(QFont::Helvetica, QFont::PreferAntialias);
    font.setPointSize(10);

    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    painter.setPen(QColor(10, 10, 10, 255));
    painter.fillRect(QRect(50, 50, 100, 100), QColor(100, 100, 100, 120));
    painter.setFont(font);
    painter.drawText(20, 20,  "hi..............................");
}
```

The problem is that `overlay->resize(event->size());` causes `SIGSEGV` when the core runs that line.

What is wrong with the code, how can I fix it?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but it looks like resizing the overlay causes the main window to also be resized. Since this happens in a resize handler, chances are it is called recursively and it ends up overflowing the stack.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi, thank you for the explanation. Do you see any way/trick to prevent resize() to resize the main window?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Qt to give you a silver bullet. I would double-check the new size of the overlay -- maybe you have to subtract some border width in order to prevent the parent from resizing as well. You can also protect your resize handler with a boolean member variable to prevent it from re-entering while resizing the overlay, but I'm not sure the results would suit you.

Comment: when I run the code via debugger, it gets the SIGSEGV the first time it reaches to ´overlay->resize(event->size())´

Comment: Please minimize the code and show a *complete* example that one can actually compile.

Comment: @Kuba Ober, it is the minimized version of the code. I already removed unnecessary buttons etc. It compiles and runs fine if 'overlay->resize(event->size())' line is commented. In that case, it shows the overlay, but the size of the overlay is wrong.

Comment: @sven Are the policy setting, tabs, etc. really necessary? Can't it all be put into a single file?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi What you describe doesn't happen.

Comment: @sven As you will be minimizing `setupui`, eventually you'll find a point when the problem doesn't happen anymore (while keeping the `Overlay` instance there). And your problem will be solved :)

Comment: -1 While a reasonable question, it is way too localized to be of use to others. Code walls aren't very helpful. It would be a good question if the code fit into it without having to scroll the code block. This is a *yet another question* that would have been solved by *not stopping the code minimization process*. Even though questions that are "solved" by further minimizing the code are really offtopic here, this one IMHO is OK, but needs minimization. Sorely.

Comment: Kuba Ober, I left the basic layout on the code and already removed so many unnecessary things. The code was 5 times longer. Feel free to edit the question. Btw, I benefited your answers about layouting, thanks for your posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is solved by `Thiago` from freenode.

He pointed that `MainWindow->showMaximized();` causes `resize()` event to be occurred before `overlay` is initialized. Removing that line or moving it to after the initialization solves the problem.

Comment: The problem would have been solved by you running it under the debugger. The backtrace would have pinpointed the issue. The call stack contains: `setupUi`, `showMaximized`, `resizeEvent`. Alternatively, if you were minimizing the code **as you should have**, you'd remove the `showMaximized` line, and the problem would vanish. So, you've ignored *two* ways of resolving it :/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at official documentation: [QWidget, Qt5](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html) at `resize` method. Here you can read

***Warning:*** Calling `resize()` or `setGeometry()` inside `resizeEvent()` can lead to infinite recursion.

You are doing exactly the same. To avoid infinite recursion and respectively your SIGSEGV you can (descending order of difficulty, descending order of *true-way*):

- overwrite your `resizeEvent()` in `Overlay` and comment that line in `MainWindow`'s `resizeEvent`;
- in `MainWindow`'s `resizeEvent` emit signal like `mainWindowSizeChanged(QSize)` and connect it to your `Overlay`'s slot;
- do `QTimer::singleShot(...)` in `MainWindow`'s `resizeEvent`, so it will call a given slot after a given time interval.

Comment: This is only true if you're calling `resize` for the same widget. It doesn't apply in this case.